# Unable to build golang rocksdb wrapper on windows 10

Tags: windows, rocksdb

I'm trying to get golang wrapper on windows but facing following error:-

```
go get github.com/tecbot/gorocksdb

# github.com/tecbot/gorocksdb
could not determine kind of name for C.rocksdb_dbpath_create
could not determine kind of name for C.rocksdb_dbpath_destroy
could not determine kind of name for C.rocksdb_dbpath_t
```

Plz help me out

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a relevant issue in GH, seems to be related to an incompatiblity between gorocksdb and rocksdb versions, see https://github.com/linxGnu/grocksdb/issues/85